# git push error Gtk

Tags: git, fedora, gnome, kde-plasma

Everytime I push something in git I get this Warning:

```
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7051): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory actions/48 of theme breeze-dark has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7051): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory categories/16 of theme breeze-dark has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7051): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory categories/22 of theme breeze-dark has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7051): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory categories/48 of theme breeze-dark has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7051): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory devices/48 of theme breeze-dark has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7051): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory actions/48 of theme breeze has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7051): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory categories/16 of theme breeze has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7051): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory categories/22 of theme breeze has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7051): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory categories/48 of theme breeze has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7051): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory devices/48 of theme breeze has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7054): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory actions/48 of theme breeze-dark has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7054): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory categories/16 of theme breeze-dark has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7054): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory categories/22 of theme breeze-dark has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7054): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory categories/48 of theme breeze-dark has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7054): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory devices/48 of theme breeze-dark has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7054): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory actions/48 of theme breeze has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7054): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory categories/16 of theme breeze has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7054): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory categories/22 of theme breeze has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7054): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory categories/48 of theme breeze has no size field
(gnome-ssh-askpass:7054): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory devices/48 of theme breeze has no size field
```

I am using Fedora 23 with KDE-Plasma Desktop (i think it has to do something with my KDE-theme)

Why is this and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: sorry. Why is this and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using KDE theme with missing files. It might go away if you choose different theme than "breeze".

Other possibility would be to unset `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable (if you don't use password authentication to `git`).

```
SSH_ASKPASS="" git push
```

if it will help you, you can add that to your `~/.bashrc` (if you use `bash`):

```
unset SSH_ASKPASS
```

or create `bash` function in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function git() {
  unset SSH_ASKPASS
  /usr/bin/git $@
}
```

(don't forget to re-login or re-`source` the `~/.bashrc` after the change)

---

or just uninstall `openssh-askpass`, which is evidently trigger:

```
dnf remove openssh-askpass
```

Comment: wouldn't it also solve the problem if I was to install the missing files? how do I find out wich files are missing?

Comment: also I cant use your last command:
dnf uninstall openssh-askpass
No such command: uninstall. Please use /usr/bin/dnf --help
It could be a DNF plugin command, try: "dnf install 'dnf-command(uninstall)'"

Comment: sorry. My bad. It is `remove`. Installing the missing files might help, but I have no idea where you found the theme (with default it should probably work without problems. If not, file a bug to `kde`).

Comment: I want to unset SSH_ASKPASS but as soon as I restart my Terminal I have to do it again. Where do I add it in ~/.bashrc, respectively in which line?

Comment: probably the last line should do that.

Comment: if I type that in, he wants to remove git and other packages that I'd like to keep. Is there any other option to remove openssh-askpass?

Comment: Nope. Just go with the other two options I gave you. Unfortunately, Ubuntu made life harder with this dependency.

Comment: I did: vim ~/.bashrc and added unset SSH_ASKPASS in the second line. It does not work. Nothing happens. Do I have to add it in a specific line, or is something else wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you unset it just before `git push`?

Comment: Try the last line of `~/.bashrc` and if it will not help, try to create bash function for example (see my edited answer).

Comment: did you `source` the `~/.bashrc` after the change or re-login?

Comment: I did `source .bashrc` and re-logged. Nothing has changed

Comment: Tricky question. What is your shell? Is it `bash`? What do you see if you type `type git`?

Comment: `type git` gives the following output: `git is hashed (/usr/bin/git)`
I think I use bash. How can I check it?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` should do that. If it does not print that it is function (as in edited answer), then is something wrong.

Comment: Output of `echo $SHELL` is `/bin/bash`

Comment: Okay, I tried it again. My exact steps were:
`cd ~` >> 
`vim ~/.bashrc` >>
there I copied your function in the second line and did 
`:wq` >>
`source ~/.bashrc` >>
`source .bashrc` >>
`cd ./gitrepopath` >>
`git push`
now it worked. maybe the source command I tried first was wrong?
thank you anyway for your patience